# How do I call a method recursively in AlpineJS?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

```
import 'alpinejs'

window.scrollToTop = () => {
    return {
        scroll() {
            const t = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
            if ( t > 0 ) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame( this.scroll )
                window.scrollTo( 0, t - t / 10 )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the following code to do a simple scroll to top animation.

Used `window.scrollToTop` as I'm using ParcelJS to bundle the project so I have to attach it to the `window` object.

And I'm getting this error when I tried running the scroll function.

> app.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scroll' of undefined

I did a console.log on the scroll click, and it seems that within the method `this.scroll` is recognised. But when called on `window.requestAnimationFrame` it becomes `undefined`? I tried passing it in as a variable but it doesn't work too. How do I call itself recursively with `requestAnimationFrame` in this case?

Comment: did you try to make a copy of this : like `that = this` before entering scroll() method and use that.scroll ?

Comment: Yup, I tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is a bit complicated when you deal with scopes.
Inside the first callback `this` reverts to window so you need to manually bind it when using those kind of functions recursively.

`window.requestAnimationFrame(this.scroll.bind(this))` should work

Comment: The binding did work! Thank you! But why didn't passing in `that = this` work in this case? Yes, after so many years scope still catches me off guard sometimes. =(

Comment: It works on the first iteration, then in the callback the function is called again and inside that function, this is window if you don't bind it because of the way setTimeout and requestAnimationFrame callbacks work. Then, the second recursive call assign this (window) to the `that` variable so when you try to call show again, it fails.